# Account link using passport without session

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I read this interesting article about how to link accounts using passport:

https://codeburst.io/account-linking-with-passportjs-in-3-minutes-2cb1b09d4a76

```
passport.use(
  new GitHubStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GithubClientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GithubClientSecret,
      callbackURL: process.env.GithubCallbackURL,
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
    (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
      const { email, name, id } = profile._json

      // Check if user is auth'd
      if (req.user) {
        // Link account
      } else {
        // Create new account
      }
    }
  )
)
```

The interesting thing is that he check if user is logged or not. If user logged in then link user account

```
if (req.user) {
   // Link account
} else {
   // Create new account
}
```

I dont know why req object has user? Maybe the user comes from session but in my NodeJS application, I use token instead of session. My question is how to attach user object to req without using session (I use jwt)?

I do like this but the req.user is undefined

```
router
    .route('/google')
    .get(
        checkToken(true),
        passport.authenticate('google', {scope: 'profile email'}),
    )
```

checkToken is a function that if we have valid token, then it will use userId (found in token) to get the user object and then attach it to req. Something like this

```
if (validToken) {
    const id = fromToken(token)
    const user = await User.findById(id)
    req.user = user
    next()
}
```

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: how to attach user object to req? I update the question